# How to validate if a DateTime includes time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that takes a `datetime` parameter. I need to determine if the given `datetime` parameter includes the time.

Now, `DATEPART(hour, @datetimeValue) = 0` doesn't work in my case because the datetime can be provided as `3/14/2019 0:00` which refers to as 12 AM and valid.

Return true if input is :

```
'3/14/2019 0:00'
'3/14/2019 15:00'
```

Return false only if input has no time :

```
'3/14/2019'
```

Thanks everyone for their input. It looks there is no solution to this other than changing the stored procedure parameter to `varchar`.

Comment: A DateTime will always have a time by default it will be:  00:00:00.000.  If you cast 1/1/2019 as DateTime you get:  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000.

Comment: If the datetime object comes from an external source, can you add another parameter indicating if the time is included?

Comment: Can't you `ALTER` your procedure and use two parameters instead, one is `DATE` and the second is `TIME`, then you can check only if they `NULL`.

Comment: I can not alter the proc. It is tight to an import process.

Comment: The requirement is not technically possible to handle server side.

Comment: **Do not use VARCHAR(n)**, that is a horrible idea.

Comment: It is technically possible but just not very elegant, think `stack trace` it also has a little bit of `code smell` (not the problem, the solution)

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is not technically possible to handle in the Stored Procedure.

The `DateTime` parameter in your stored procedure will always contain a time aspect which is either explicitly passed to it *or* defaults to midnight of the passed in date. There is no way to know if the caller explicitly passed in a time aspect or not.

You have 2 options:

1. Change the incoming data type of the parameter to `varchar` and have the stored procedure parse that into a `DateTime` and handle validation.
2. Make the caller handle any validation having to do with time and drop this requirement from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to `ALTER` your SP and use two (2) parameters instead, one is `DATE` and the second is `TIME` datatype as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HasTime(
    @MyDate DATE = NULL,
    @MyTime TIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @MyTime IS NULL
        SELECT 'There is no time'
            ELSE
                SELECT 'There is time';
END;

EXEC dbo.HasTime '2019-01-01', NULL; --Or EXEC dbo.HasTime '2019-01-01';
EXEC dbo.HasTime '2019-01-01', '00:00:00';
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fcc2c25609da5c74433885aa6b9eee0d)**

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `DATETIME` includes a time, set to midnight (e.g. '00:00:00'), even if you aren't using the time portion. If your datetime's are strings, then here is a way to see if a time is part of the string (though it's a little hacky):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', '3/14/2019 0:00') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   -- Returns 1
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', '3/14/2019 15:00') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  -- Returns 1
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', '3/14/2019') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END        -- Returns 0
```

Basically it's just searching the string and looking to see if a colon is in the string. It meets your criteria though.

Comment: The problem is the stored procedure accepts a datetime parameter

Answer (score 1):

This is crude, but it does what you need. If its throw away, eg part of some import it might be good enough for your needs.

I am sure this approach could be improved with more understanding on how to retreive details of the current executing `SQL` from within the `PROC`, I had a quick look at using `query plans` etc.

**You could just fail back to this check if the time is *midnight* this makes it more efficient**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Hastime(@d AS DATETIME) 
AS 
  BEGIN

      -- Is there a easier way to get from DBCC INPUTBUFFER to a SQL variable? 
      CREATE TABLE #temp 
        ( 
           spid       INT, 
           eventtype  NVARCHAR(30), 
           parameters INT, 
           eventinfo  NVARCHAR(4000) 
        )     
      INSERT INTO #temp 
                  (eventtype, 
                   parameters, 
                   eventinfo) 

      EXEC ('DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + @@spid +') WITH NO_INFOMSGS') 

      -- Yes, we could do this better
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM   #temp 
                 WHERE  eventinfo LIKE '%:%') 
        SELECT 'Time' 
      ELSE 
        SELECT 'No Time' 
  END     
go     
EXEC dbo.Hastime 
  '2000/06/01' 

go     
EXEC dbo.Hastime 
  '2000/06/01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check like this, but if the time is actually midnight, it will return not valid time:

```
-- returns 'NOTime'
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST('1/1/2019' AS TIME) = '00:00:00.000' THEN 'NOTime' ELSE 'TIME' END

-- returns 'TIME'
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(GetDate() AS TIME) = '00:00:00.000' THEN 'NOTime' ELSE 'TIME' END
```

Comment: That's exactly my point. I must accept midnight as a valid time.Because it is a valid time.

Comment: Then for your check the data type cant be datetime because it will always default to midnight if no date exists.  If you pass it as a data type of varchar(), you can do the above check/conversion to check if a time was passed/is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would cast as `date`:

```
select (case when convert(date, @datetimeValue) = @datetimeValue then 'NoTime'
             else 'HasTime'
        end)
```

Comment: Nice, but [that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a72a40a096df09c85072451beb20aef2) won't work.

Comment: @Sami . . . I'm not sure the point.  A `datetime` value is *always* going to have a time component.  Hence, for the OP's question to make sense, it must be referring to a time component different from a date column.

Comment: I think the point is that 00:00:00.000 will return NoTime, but the OP wants that considered as having time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to pass a varchar type to teh procedure instead of datetime
otherwise we can not make difference between a date without time and a date at midnight
here you can check this restriction
The follwoing script illustrates that restriction:

```
declare @d as datetime
declare @d1 as datetime

set @d='01/01/2019'
set @d1='01/01/2019 00:00:00:00'

if @d=@d1 print 'equal' else print 'not equal'
```